# How do I set up 2 entities to run a query join using an indexed key

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to create two tables, er entities:

```
User { UserID: String, UserName: String }
UserSession { SessionID: String, UserID: String, LoginTime: Date }
```

Using the console dashboard in gae, I can't seem to be able to define the UserSession's UserID (a sort of secondary key) to represent the key in the first entity such as `Key('User', 'UserID')`. The syntax fails.

Extra issue: I can't define the LoginTime as a date because it wants a default value. Why can't the property be set as blank when creating the entity?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I am using. Can you please validate if this is the right way to get back user data by linking the entities with parenting?

```
package testapp

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/datastore"
)

type User struct {
    Name       string
    FullName   string `datastore:",noindex"`
    Password   string `datastore:",noindex"`
    IsDisabled bool   `datastore:",noindex"`
}

type Session struct {
    LoginTime time.Time `datastore:",noindex"`
    LastSeen  time.Time `datastore:",noindex"`
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    u := User{
        Name:       "john",
        FullName:   "John Difool",
        Password:   "secret",
        IsDisabled: false}

    userId, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "user", nil), &u)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    s := Session{
        LoginTime: time.Now(),
        LastSeen:  time.Now()}

    key, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "session", userId), &s) // parent is user
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // store key and later on get it back

    t := new(Session)
    if err := datastore.Get(c, key, t); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // let's get back user's data using parent key

    e := new(User)
    if err := datastore.Get(c, key.Parent(), e); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "name=%q\npassword=%q\n", e.Name, e.Password)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? Can you post your code

Comment: I updated the question with some code. I skipped the console entirely and went programmatically because it seems easier to describe that way. I'd like to understand better the key hierarchy aspect of datastores. I find it still a bit confusing coming from RDBMS.